# jQuery autoComplete doesn't work although jQuery-UI is included

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I tried to research this subject but everything I found referred to the common error of not including the jquery-ui file into the header. I however do have jquery first and then jquery-ui. I host the files locally but I have also tried to copy the most updated cdn links from the official sites to be sure of not having made whatever weird typing error or host an outdated file. 
It still doesn't work, I always get "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autoComplete is not a function"
Do you have any idea what could be wrong apart from the missing jquery-ui file?

My header looks like this:

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dataTables.tableTools.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
```

The Jquery code part of the autocomplete looks as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function () {
  $(".auto").autoComplete({
    source: "soplogsave.php",
    minLength: 3
  });
});
```

and html:

```
<p><label>Country:</label><input type='text' name='country' value='' class='auto'></p>
```

I can post the php code aswell but I'm not sure it's relevant, as I have already tried using preconfigured variables in jquery and it still didn't work, i still got the "autocomplete is not a function" error.

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console when the page loads or when you try to use the autocomplete?

Comment: I use a lot of other jquery and everything works fine. I get exactly one error which concerns the autocomplete: **Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autoComplete is not a function**. I get this error by page load. Are there any issues that can cause jquery not recognizing the autocomplete or something?

Comment: It's `autocomplete()` not `autoComplete()`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Ugh, yes that was it. Can't explain how I wasn't able to figure that out :) thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have to write autocomplete not autoComplete.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```